# while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) -- why set>0?

Tags: c

I am having difficulty understanding why the author chose to set

```
(len = getline(line, MAXLINE))>0
```

Below is the code from Example K&R 1-19.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */
main()
{
        int len;                /* current line length          */
        int max;                /* maximum length seen so far   */
        char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line           */
        char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here      */

        max = 0;
        while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                if (len > max) {
                        max = len;
                        copy(longest, line);
                }
        if (max > 0)            /* there was a line */
            printf("%s", longest);
        return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
        int c, i;

        for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
                s[i] = c;
        if (c == '\n') {
                s[i] = c;
                ++i;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
        return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'c'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
        int i;

        i = 0;
        while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
                ++i;
}
```

My understanding of code is as follows:

1. The getline function is invoked.
2. The getline function requests input(s) from the user.
3. If the user input(s) is not an EOF, carriage return, and if the total user input does not exceed 998 in length, the first character's ASCII value is stored in s[1], the second character's value is stored in s[2], and so forth. During this time simultaneously, for each character inputted, the value of i is increased by 1.
4. If the user breaks one of those three conditions, the loop is terminated.
5. The less than lim-1 ensures that in a worse case situation, the 999th value is ASCII of the carriage return and the null value is inserted into 1000th value.
6. The getline function spits out a single number, the final value of i.
7. The loop will run as long as i is > 0.

My Question: Removing > 0 from

```
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
```

Does not seem to affect the outcome of the code. It still operates as normal.
Why does removing the >0 not affect the outcome of the code? And why does the author put >0 in, if it does not affect the outcome of the code?

Comment: Note: "_the first character's ASCII value is stored in_ `s[0]`, not `s[1]` as arrays in C start at 0.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does removing the >0 not affect the outcome of the code?

This is because your `getline()` function returns either a positive integer or `0` if case of `EOF`.  So the statement :

```
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
```

is equivalent to :

```
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)))
```

which actually checks the condition inside `while` and evaluates it to `true` or `false`. In a `while` loop, if you have ***any integer value, except for `0`***, as a condition, it ***is evaluated as `true`***. Only `0` is evaluated as `false`.

So if the user immediately enters `EOF`, the number of characters read will be `0` and the `while` loop condition evaluated to `false`. If you remove `>0`, it is the same as if you don't. The purpose of adding it is for clarification reasons.

See [this link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100408050145AA7J8CX) on how conditions like this work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that getline() returns the number of characters read, but if the user immediately enters EOF, the number of characters read will be zero. In my understanding, if you remove the ">0" portion, this should cause the program to run in an infinity loop, but the program does not. Instead, it operates as normal. Why is this the case? And if it operates as normal, what is the purpose of adding the >0 portion?

Comment: @sp2danny This `getline` implementation can never return -1 !

Comment: I was under the impression that len = getline(line, MAXLINE) set len to the value spit out by getline. If it was evaluating it whether to be true or false, would the correct operand not be ==? @Marievi

Comment: @JohnDoe yes right, `len` gets the value that `getline` returns. But the condition `while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)` actually means `while (positive integer in here)`. The `>0` part is used just for clarification reasons.

Comment: @JohnDoe have you ever seen the condition `while(1)`? We usually don't write `while(1>0)`. It is exactly the same with your case.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am still confused but I am testing out the condition you wrote to see what insight I may gain.

Comment: @JohnDoe see the link I edited my post with. To put it simply, `while (x)` means `while(x > 0)`. So if `x` has a non-zero value, the program enters the `while` loop, otherwise if `x` is `0`, it doesn't. Ask further for any other question!

Comment: That is very interesting, what you say is correct. It does seem to be the case.

Does this mean that if I put a = operand in a loop

For (;x=y;)
While (x=y)

The interpretation: is the value of x, (which is derived from the value of y) is greater than 0.

Whereas if i put 

For(;x==y;)
While(x==y)

The interpretation is: "While the value of x equals the value of y"

@Marievi

Comment: @JohnDoe exactly. `while(x=y)` means that `y` is assigned to `x` and if this value is nonzero, the loop is executed.  `while(x==y)` means `while the value of x equals the value of y` (which can also be mapped to a boolean operation, as, if x==y, then `while` gets a positive (non-zero) value, otherwise if x!=y, then `while` gets value `0`).

Answer (score 0):

While condition is true if `len` is not zero.
Otherwise it will step out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because this specific implementation of `getline` returns 0 on end of file and returns a value (strictly) greater than 0 in any other case.

And in a boolean context (in a test or loop condition), any int value is true except 0.

So both:

```
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
```

and

```
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) /* same as while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE) != 0)
```

will loop until end of file.